# Reload or compile just one file without restar the server nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, updates

i´m doing a project in node js and i have one problem, Update files to production.
I know that exist, nodemon and supervisor that when you make a change in any file restarts the server but i just one to update the file that a changed. The problem with these packages is when you restart the server all the connections ends, so the user needs to log in again.

There is package that only compiles just one file?

Comment: You can't easily exchange a part in your car's engine while it's running... that's why the server is restarted. You should rather think about why you even have this problem in the first place? For not logging in again, I guess you should implement a session storage. But in general, are you updating your application every 3 minutes with real users on it? Then something is wrong ;-) In production, you would avoid closing connections by having a load balancer and multiple instances of your app in parallel, and then one by one stopping new connections, completing old ones, then updating&restarting

Comment: in the old system,  was made it with vfp and when the client needed a change in some file i just compile the file and upload the file in the server without restart it. I would like to do something like this